# Qt комментарии в VS

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Увидел недавно интересный тип комментариев в C++: **/*! */**. После небольших скитаний по гуглу увидел что это тип комментариев **Qt**, которые также идут с тегами (**@brief**, **@return** и т.д.). После открытия документации в **Notepad++** он подсвечивает их другим цветом, а также выделяет теги. Но я в использую **VS**, и поэтому назрел вопрос, а можно ли как-то активировать эти теги в **VS**, что-бы они как-то обрабатывались, или хотя бы просто выделялись, т.к. сейчас визуал их воспринимает как простой набор текста в комментариях.

Comment: По-моему вы говорите о комментариях Doxygen ([статья на habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/252101/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. [ReSharper C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) понимает [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org).